# Adding jackson-module-kotlin results in reflective access warning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

After upgrading to Java 11 and all current library versions, I get a warning when running my (spring boot) application:
`o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder: For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath`
(note that to my knowledge I do not use Kotlin classes…)

Adding the `jackson-module-kotlin` dependency (version 2.11.3) to the pom file, gets rid of this warning, but then I get a reflective access warning.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.10.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this properly? Neither warning sounds fully ignorable…

Comment: You may depend transitively on `kotlin-stdlib` (or something similar). For example `okhttp3` uses it. Check the dependency tree to see if there is any Kotlin library used (`mvn dependency:tree | grep -B10 kotlin`).

Comment: @AndreiDamian-Fekete, yes, it depends on kotlin-stdlib. The output from the dep tree shows it is used by com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4.
BUT that very same info is reported by another application that doesn't cause the reflective access error (or at least not anymore, in the meantime I've updated a.o. the spring framework).

Comment: did you ever solve this?  getting the same msg

Comment: No, I have not (yet) been able to completely get rid of the reflective access error 
It's only happening in one application and it seems harmless, but still, I'd like to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

To “answer” my own question: The issue no longer seems to be present with newer Spring versions.